# Slow performance of Latitude/Longitude conversion in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sqlgeography

I have a performance problem with a SQL query running on SQL Server 2019 that returns the lat/long from a geography column.
My query is as follows and it takes around 5 seconds to return 553 rows:

```
SELECT ActivityLocations.ID, ActivityLocations.ActivityID, ActivityLocations.Number, ActivityLocations.Location.Lat AS 'Latitude', ActivityLocations.Location.Long AS 'Longitude'
FROM Plans
INNER JOIN Activities ON Plans.ID = Activities.PlanID
INNER JOIN ActivityLocations ON Activities.ID = ActivityLocations.ActivityID
WHERE CustomerID = 35041
```

The query plan it generates is:
[image: Slow Query Plan]

But if I change the query a little to return a bit less data, it takes 0 seconds to return 207 rows:

```
SELECT ActivityLocations.ID, ActivityLocations.ActivityID, ActivityLocations.Number, ActivityLocations.Location.Lat AS 'Latitude', ActivityLocations.Location.Long AS 'Longitude'
FROM Plans
INNER JOIN Activities ON Plans.ID = Activities.PlanID
INNER JOIN ActivityLocations ON Activities.ID = ActivityLocations.ActivityID
WHERE PlanID > 22486
```

And the query plan is:
[image: Fast query Plan]

I guess my question, is why is the Compute Scalar operation happening before the join on the slow query and after the join on the fast query?  I don't understand why it would do the Lat/Long operation on every row the activity locations table when we only want a small subset of the rows?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edited to contain table information

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Activities](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PlanID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Activity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityLocations](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActivityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Location] [geography] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivityLocations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityPlans](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseOrder] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivityPlan] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PlanID_IX] ON [dbo].[Activities]
(
    [PlanID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ActivityID_IX] ON [dbo].[ActivityLocations]
(
    [ActivityID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([Number],[Location]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CustomerID_NCIX] ON [dbo].[ActivityPlans]
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: If you want an accurate answer, you need to [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and provide DDL scripts for the used tables. The order in which the `Compute Scalar` operator is being used is a symptom of the problem, and not the issue. Your second query that you changed `to return a bit less data` is using a different column `PlanID` in the filter predicate, one that is able to seek the index `ActivityID_IX` of the table `ActivityLocations`, which means that same seek cannot be done using the `CustomerID` column of your first query which is the reason for the difference.

Comment: You can also try updating statistics.

Comment: Hi Trenton, thank you very much for your help!  Here is the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1pxmjcpY
Before generating this execution plan, I created a copy of the Plans table, named ActivityPlans and used that in this example.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for response too.  I updated the statistics for the three tables in this query, but that didn't seem to make any difference.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Stephen looks like you left out the defined indexes on your tables out of the DDL scripts. For example, in your query plan we see the index `ActivityID_IX` on the table `ActivityLocations`, but it is not included in the DDL scripts you provided. If you are unsure of how to do that, you can follow [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-table-script-with-their-all-indexes-in-sql-server1) link on how to do it.

Comment: Hi Trenton, thank you again. I have updated the original question to include the indexes

Comment: @Stephen don't change the name of any tables between your original question and then the posted DDL scripts and paste the plan. People aren't going to answer your questions on SO if you make changes like that.

Comment: @trenton-ftw, sorry about that.  I wasn't expecting to provide so much detail and the original Plans table had some column names that I didn't feel appropriate to share.  How would you like me to rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**: OP changed the name of the table `Plans` to `ActivityPlans` between the originally posted queries/graphical executions plans and his subsequently provided execution plan (via paste the plan) and DDL scripts. I am going to speak in terms of the table `Plans` (as it was originally posted).

I am going to try to explain this in its entirety, including trying to note the things that are not an issue between these two queries because the obvious differences when looking at the two queries is not resulting in the issue (per se). Read on to see my explanation.

### Similarities

First, lets talk about where the two execution plans are similar. It is important to note the similarities because (assuming second query plan is acceptable for the OP) the issues is not with the similarities between the two query plans.

- Both execution plans start by accessing the tables `Plans` and `Activities`.

  - The table accessed first changes based on your `WHERE` clause. Which is good. The optimizer makes a good decision and is able to use an index seek in both cases. The filter `WHERE CustomerID = 35041` is resolved to an index seek on the index `CustomerID_NCIX` of the `Plans` table and the filter `WHERE PlanID > 22486` is resolved to an index seek on the index `PlanID_IX` of the `Activities` table. Then the join to the subsequent table (`Activities` in the first query and `Plans` in the second query) is done. It is supported by an index in both cases, the estimates for the seek operations are not horrific, and both joins are done using Nested Loops that output a number that is relatively close to the final result set. So even though the only visual difference in these two queries is the difference in the `WHERE` clause, it appears the `WHERE` clause in each query is being handled fairly similarly and does not appear to be an issue.
- The actual order that all 3 tables used in both the first and second query are accessed in the same order in both execution plans.
- Both queries access the table `ActivityLocations` using the index `ActivityID_IX`.
- Both queries have a `Compute Scalar` operator that retrieves the required values for your expressions `ActivityLocations.Location.Lat` and `ActivityLocations.Location.Long` from `ActivityLocations.Location` of your `SELECT` statement.

### Differences

Now lets talk about the (important) differences, which is where the issues lie.

- The first query accesses the table `ActivityLocations` using an Index Seek operator, while the second query uses an Index Scan operator.
- The Index Scan operator that accesses the table `ActivityLocations` of the first query has an Actual/Estimated Row Count of 329,475/331,523 and the Index Seek operator that accesses the table `ActivityLocations` of the second query has an Actual/Estimated Row Count of 207/9.
- The first query uses a Merge Join to join the results of the first two tables (`Plans` and `Activities`) and the second query uses a Nested Loop Join.
- The Compute Scalar operator to retrieve the needed values from ActivityLocations.Location of the first query has an Actual/Estimated Row Count of 329,475/331,523 and in the second query it has an Actual/Estimated Row Count of 207/9.
- The actual/estimated number of rows in the output of the final join of the first query increases from its input Sort operator (471/3341->553/3402) while the actual/estimated number of rows in the output of the final join of the second query remains consistent from its input Nested Loop operator (207->207).

### What is the actual problem?

Put simply, the first query is reading much more data when we look at the execution plan. The rows read from the table `ActivityLocations` of roughly 300k in the first query is much higher than the 207 rows read in the second query. Additionally, the Compute Scalar operator of the first query is required to compute values for (the same) roughly 300k rows as opposed to the 207 rows of the second query. This obviously leads to a longer running query.

It is also worth noting that the larger row counts coming from the table `ActivityLocations` is the reason for the Merge Join (seen in the first query plan) in place of the Nested Loop Join operator (seen in the second query plan). According to the optmizer, given your environment, a Merge Join is more suitable to join 300k rows to 3.3k rows than a Nested Loop Join would be. And the use of a Merge Join requires both sides of the join to be sorted by the join columns, thus the reason for the additional Sort operator in the query plan of the first query.

### Why is it happening?

Estimates. Estimates drive the optimizer's decision making. In the first query we see that the estimated number of rows to read from the table `ActivityLocations` (from the Index Scan) is 331,523 and in the second query (from the Index Seek) we see an estimate of 9. It might seem odd to say, but these estimates are closer than you might think. An Index Scan (on up to date statistics) is usually going to have row estimates equivalent to the rows in the table (except for filtered indexes). An Index Seek would ideally estimate a lower number of rows than what is contained in the table. Ideally that number would match the actual number of rows that the Index Seek is required to touch, but the fact that your Index Seek estimate is lower than the entire table is a step in the right direction.

So if the issue is not with the estimates in the Index Scan or Index Seek then where is it? **The issue is in the choice to access the table `ActivityLocations` using an Index Scan in the first query over the choice to use an Index Seek**. So why does the first query choose an Index Scan? It is quite clear by looking at the execution plan that an Index Seek would have been a better option. I believe the answer in this case is the cardinality estimation, specifically in this case, the cardinality estimation used for the join to the table `ActivityLocations`.

We see that the estimated number of rows in the output of the final join of the first query increases from its input Sort operator (3341->3402) while the estimated number of rows in the output of the final join of the second query remains consistent from its input Nested Loop operator (207->207). And not only did the optimzer estimate this, it was right. The actual rows counts returned from these same operators reflect the same pattern.

Why does that matter? What it means is that based on the optimizer's estimate, the join to the table `ActivityLocations` is going to increase the row count of the input result set. Meaning this join is going to be 1 (input row) to many (output row). Keep in mind, the optimizer needs to return your requested values `ActivityLocations.Location.Lat` and `ActivityLocations.Location.Long` from the table `ActivityLocations`. So when it considers this join, that it believes is going to increase the rows it plans to output from accessing the table `ActivityLocations` while keeping in mind that it needs to perform a Compute Scalar on columns output from that table, it would make sense to run the Compute Scalar prior to running the join because if the Compute Scalar is run before the join it can guarantee that the Compute Scalar is only running once per row of `ActivityLocations`, but it cannot guarantee that if the Compute Scalar is run after the join. In this case, the join is actually what ends up limiting the rows from `AcitivityLocations` and the number of rows returned from that table (for the purposes of this query) is much lower than the row count of the table. In the second query, the estimate says that the output number of rows will be the same, so running the Compute Scalar after the join makes no difference to the number of rows where the compute will be required, so it makes sense to perform the Index Seek in place of the Index Scan.

So to summarize, the rows returned from the first two tables of your first and second query (using your `WHERE` clause) are different. And it is likely that the rows returned from the first query resulted in a join estimation that estimated a different cardinality than the second query. Thus the differences in how the query plan was built and how it was subsequently run.

Cardinality estimation (with joins specifically) is made up of several factors. If you really want to get in to the internals I would recommend these two articles from the legend [Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/11/sql-optimizer/histogram-coarse-alignment) and [SQL Shack](https://www.sqlshack.com/join-estimation-internals/). The things discussed there should guide you on how you can review the estimation within your system.

### How to fix it?

The first goal would be to improve the estimate. If the estimated cardinality for the join was incorrect (which is actually not the case here) then updating the statistics might help. Out of date statistics could lead to a bad cardinality estimate, and thus a bad query plan.

In some cases you might be able to restructure your query to a logical equivalent to result in a better execution plan. This might be by writing it to produce better estimates or even possibly returning different rows in different orders. In this case, I would say the first query looks fine to me, and thus rewriting the query for a logical equivalent would likely not help.

In this case, the cardinality estimate is correct (and you mentioned that you updated statistics and it did not help), the query appears to be written in a good fashion, but the execution plan chosen is still sub-optmial. So I would recommend a query hint. This problem would easily be solved with a query hint to seek the index `ActivityID_IX` of `ActivityLocations`. Your join in your first query would look like so:

```
INNER JOIN ActivityLocations (WITH FORCESEEK,INDEX(ActivityID_IX)) ON Activities.ID = ActivityLocations.ActivityID
```

There is plenty of information out there on why query hints might be a bad idea, but given the information I have here I would say that is the best option. I am always open to other opinion. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much Trenton!  The query hint you suggested resolved the issue.  And thank you for taking the time to explain the issue in depth and helping me understand what was happening and why.  Greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hints are fragile, especially for this dataset which is unlikely to see update changes.  Go with indexes - they will be stable, storage is cheap, and updates to the affected indexes will be rare, if not "never occurring".

Comment: storage is cheap for small data. indexes are not just storage, again not a problem with small data. issues with using hints (as mentioned in post) are documented out there for all to see.  indexes don't solve the cardinality issue pointed out in my post. if this data is `unlikely to see update changes` as you put it (which OP does not state) then a hint is actually much less 'fragile'. maybe 3 indexes that don't solve the cardinality issue is what OP wants, but I would suggest its not  the best solution and a hint is a much lower cost alternative.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the indexes themselves: your Customer ID can occur anywhere in the Plans table, whereas in the second query, the greater-than on the PlanID means you are limiting the query to only the end of the table because the clustered index (the index which determines the actual ordering of rows in the Plan table) is on PlanID.

As a result, the query planner is making different choices about how to sequence the query execution.

Your best option here is to add three additional indexes:

- First on Plan with fields CustomerID, PlanID
- Second on Activities with PlanID, ActivityID
- Third on ActivityLocations with ActivityID, ID, Number, Lat, Long

This allows the query engine to:

- immediately find the rows in Plan for a customer using the first index
- take those PlanIDs and use the second index to immediately find the Activities for those Plans (looking up Activities by PlanID)
- take those ActivityIDs and use the third index to immediately return the resulting ID, Number, Lat, Long

Comment: This answer is wrong on several counts. The `PlanID` column is not the clustered index on any of the tables involved in the query. Adding three indexes is not required in order to make the first query run just as fast (or with similar number reads) as the second query.

Comment: @trenton-ftw late response, but the Plans table is clustered on PlanID (ID in that table, but it's joined to PlanID, which anchors the join to the clustered ID of Plans).  Indexes are storage-expensive and update-expensive, but read-cheap.  In GIS data sets, lat/lon pairs don't change alot, neither generally do plan/customer relationships, nor activity/plan relationships, so updates that would alter these indexes would be rare.  I appreciate you taking the time to analyze my response, but your statement is dead wrong: PlanID is "involved" by join association to the clustered index on Plans.

Comment: right, `ID` is the clustered index of the Plans table, not `PlanID`. As stated, no table in the posted DDL scripts has a clustered index with a `PlanID` column in it. contrary to your post that states `because the clustered index (the index which determines the actual ordering of rows in the Plan table) is on PlanID`